# SSL certificates on iisnode

Tags: node.js, ssl, iis, iisnode

I want to host my NodeJs app on my Windows Server.
I already have my server running, but on http. Now I want my server to use HTTPS, but i'm not being able to add my certificates to issnode.

I've added the certificates like this:
[image]

but didn't worked.

Comment: This doesn't work do you get any error messages? How did you bind the certificate? have you configure SSL Settings? [Configure SSL Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis#configure-ssl-settings-2).